# Count sent emails per day in a google managed domain

Tags: gmail

I have a requirement where I have to count all sent email by users belonging to a domain that they manage with google. All email is of course managed with gmail.

Although this task initialy seemed trivial, there doesn't seem to be a way to do this directly, meaning through some API call.

Any ideas?

Thanks
Stelios

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the [Gmail API](http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/) doesn't offer access to the total of send items.

Tthe [g4j project](http://g4j.sourceforge.net/) (written in Java) reverse engineered Gmail's protocol in order to access an account using HTTP calls. However, the solution is fragile since it could be easily broken whenever Gmail decides to change its HTTP protocol.

Screenshot of a Java application build on top of g4j:

[image]

It's not easy but there is a way to access a gmail account.

Comment: Yes i've checked that project already but as you said it's not a robust way of doing it. You would have thought this is standard functionality offered by google... There is this btw: http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/class_mailapp.html#getRemainingDailyQuota. But still you would have to do it separately for each user in your domain.

Comment: Yes, they are still missing a stronger API. The "getRemainingDailyQuota()" method seems the best way to go for now.